# Size of equations in tables

Tags: tables, equations

I'm trying to insert multiple equations in a `tabular` environment in LaTeX. My problem is simple yet I haven't found any particular solution to it: the equations displayed are too small, and I'd like to increase their size so that I can obtain something less ugly than that (especially the last equation):

[image: What I got so far...]

I tried various tricks found here and there (`\displaystyle`, `\def\arraystretch{3}`, etc.), but nothing work really well.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It may just be that you're not placing `\displaystyle` in the appropriate place. Here are some options, and there are *many* more, depending on your requirements:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\verb|tabular (default)|:\par
\begin{tabular}{ccl}
  Eq1 & $\sum_{i=1}^N |x A_i-x_i^B|$ & $a+b-2c$ \\ \\
  Eq2 & $\sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^N(x A_i-x B_i)^2}$ & $\sqrt{a+b-2c}$ \\ \\
  Eq3 & $\frac{\sum_{i=0}^N|x A_i-x B_i|}{\sum_{i=0}^N\max(x A_i-x B_i)}$ & $\frac{a+b-2c}{a+b-c}$
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

\verb|tabular (\displaystyle)|:\par
\begin{tabular}{ccl}
  Eq1 & $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^N |x A_i-x_i^B|$ & $a+b-2c$ \\ \\
  Eq2 & $\displaystyle\sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^N(x A_i-x B_i)^2}$ & $\sqrt{a+b-2c}$ \\ \\
  Eq3 & $\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^N|x A_i-x B_i|}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^N\max(x A_i-x B_i)}$ & 
    $\displaystyle\frac{a+b-2c}{a+b-c}$
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

\verb|array (amsmath)|:\par
\[\begin{array}{c@{\quad}c@{\qquad}l}
  \text{Eq1} & \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^N |x A_i-x_i^B| & a+b-2c \\ \\
  \text{Eq2} & \displaystyle\sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^N(x A_i-x B_i)^2} & \sqrt{a+b-2c} \\ \\
  \text{Eq3} & \dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^N|x A_i-x B_i|}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^N\max(x A_i-x B_i)} & 
    \dfrac{a+b-2c}{a+b-c}
\end{array}\]

\end{document}
```

Since you are displaying math, it's advisable to use an `array` environment, or perhaps [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `align` environments. This would allow you to automatically number the equations.

You can change the spacing between columns using a `@{<stuff>}` specifier (as I've done in the last example). Vertical spacing is achieved through adding additional empty rows, or increasing `\arraystretch`. For more on this topic, see [Column padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31704/5764).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I didn't known that the \displaystype had to be used inside \frac as well. Now the equations are much more sexy :)

Comment: Thank you indeed - is there a way to set \displaystyle globally and as a default for all arrays?

Comment: Never mind, it's \everymath{\displaystyle} before \begin{document}

Comment: Thanks for posting! I tested your suggestions and they look really fine! Thanks for sharing!