# Insert image and formula inside a table

Tags: tables, floats, equations

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c}
    \hline
        Shape && R\textsubscript{hyd} \\
        \hline
        circle 
        & \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=2cm, height= 2cm]{images/circle}
        \end{minipage}
        & $\frac{8\mu L}{\pi r^{4}}$ \\[1cm]
        ellipse 
        & \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=2cm, height= 2cm]{images/ellipse}
        \end{minipage}
        &$\frac{4\mu L}{\pi a^{4}} \frac{1+(b/a)^{2}}{(b/a}^{3}$ \\[1cm]
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I have a problem with the size of equations. It gets compressed and readability is gone. Also the figure couldnot be centered vertically.

Comment: Regarding a vertically centered image in a table cell: [How to vertically center text with an image in the same row of a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199644/134144); Regarding too small equations in table cells: [Size of equations in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77669/134144)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maths inside an `array` or a `tabularx` is displayed by default in `\textstyle`, so fractions look petty. You can use the `\dfrac` command from `amsmath` to have fractions in `\displaystyle`. Another possibility is the `\mfrac` command (*medium-size* fractions) from `nccmath` which are  ~ 80% of \displaystyle. Both are used in this code:

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array, amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c}
\hline
    Shape && R\textsubscript{hyd} \\
    \hline
    circle
    & \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=2cm, height= 2cm]{images/circle}
    \end{minipage}
    & $\mfrac{8\mu L}{\pi r^{4}}$ \\[1cm]
    ellipse
    & \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=2cm, height= 2cm]{images/ellipse}
    \end{minipage}
    &$\dfrac{4\mu L}{\pi a^{4}} \dfrac{1+(b/a)^{2}}{(b/a)^{3}}$ \\[1cm]
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]